# How to calculate the variance in this situation?

Tags: probability, variance

I have the following situation.

There is a vector of probabilities, say [0.9 0.8 1 1]. Each probability corresponds to an item that may be added to the final item-list. So that there is a 90% chance the first item will be included, an 80% chance the second item will be included, and a 100% chance the third and fourth will be included.

It's somewhat intuitive that the sum of these values gives you the expected value for the number of items to be included in the item-list (0.9+0.8+1+1 = 3.7).

What is the variance? How would I calculate that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have my own answer. If we consider each of these items to be a Bernoulli trial, the variance for each item is p(1-p) where p is the probability that item is included, and the sum of the variances is the variance of the sum, so the variance would be 0.9 * 0.1 + 0.8 * 0.2 + 1 * 0 + 1 * 0 = 0.25.